# laravel livewire return blank page after submit form

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Im learning laravel livewire but i encounter this problem, i followed the tutorial in youtube but i dont know what is the problem.

login.blade.php
I have this in form tag **wire:submit.prevent="submit"**

app.blade.php

```
 @livewireStyles
   <livewire:login />
 @livewireScripts
```

Login Component

```
public $form = [
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
];

public function submit()
{
   $this->validate([
        'form.username' => 'required',
        'form.password' => 'required'
    ]);

}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.login');
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from the `submit` function.

Comment: @Unflux i see the problem, its because the login blade and app.blade have both body tag. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @Unflux You don't have to return anything in a Livewire component. The problem is that there's no logic in the action method, so it's just not doing anything

Comment: change name submit to Store or Update  and  share `livewire/Login.blade.php`

Answer (score 2):

I have same error.
My code is:

```
@if($errors->any())
   <ul>
       [laravel error loop]
   </ul>
@endif


<div class="anything">
   <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
      ....form tags....
   </form>
</div>
```

It seems livewire not rendering any other html after perfectly closed, like above, after `</ul>` is closed, then the rest is no rendering

Then I change my code to:

```
<div class="anything">
   @if($errors->any())
      <ul>
         [laravel error loop]
      </ul>
   @endif


   <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
      ....form tags....
   </form>
</div>
```

I wrap all elements in one `<div>`, in this case I use `<div class="anything">` And it works!
My form rendered!